# Bulk Insert Type Mismatch T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012-express

Am using this BULK INSERT command to insert a csv file in SQL Server 2012 Express.

```
BULK INSERT dbo.TS_FX
   FROM 'c:\fxRates.csv'
   WITH 
   (
      FIELDTERMINATOR =',',
      ROWTERMINATOR =',\n'
   );
```

The First Row on the fxRatesCSV file looks like this:

```
101,20130430,20130531,1.5307
```

The error I get is:

> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 4 (FX_RATE).

My table (`dbo.TS_FX`) has 4 columns in it defined as follows

```
CURRENCY_ID (Numeric(3,0), null)
BEGIN_DATE (date, null)
END_DATE (date, null)
FX_RATE (float, null)
```

Clearly the error is the way I have defined the `FX_RATE` column, I have tried various other types (`Decimal, Numeric`) but I still get the same error

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can't reproduce - works just fine for me (SQL Server 2012 Developer). I wouldn't use `float` myself - it's not precise - use `decimal(10,4)` or something like that instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the comma from ROWTERMINATOR

Your BULK INSERT statement should look like this:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.TS_FX
FROM 'c:\fxRates.csv'
WITH (
     FIELDTERMINATOR =','
    ,ROWTERMINATOR ='\n'
);
```